# Operating Systems Qualifying Exam Visual Study Aids

Tags: operating-systems

I have read the [Operating System Concepts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_System_Concepts) book, watched a lot of videos on YouTube, practiced with past qualifying exam questions and several exams from other CS departments around the world.

Although I feel better about going into the exam, I have been searching for:

- Large diagram that puts *most* of OS concepts in perspective
- Video that shows the lifecycle of a process, etc…

I can undersand full-well why such a digram may not exist. It is possible to propose a case of a concept then diagram its "life-cycle"... but I havent found one. Has anyone see anything like this? I am a very visual person and things make more sense to me when I can express them in a diagram.

At this point I feel that I will draw the diagram myself, and this way I can test my knowledge and also share it with others. But before I do that, I want to make sure I am not re-inventing the wheel.

***If you are going to down-vote my question, please leave a comment also.***

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for.  There's a ton of state diagrams showing the "lifecycle" of a process.  Like http://www.technologyuk.net/computing/operating_systems/images/process_state_diagram02.gif or (more detailed) http://web.cs.mun.ca/~paul/cs3725/material/web/notes/img85.gif.  But presumably you are asking for something more than that?  What?

Comment: I don't see any requests for opinions here, so I don't understand why people are voting to close as "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: It's not clear what the question is asking for.  Without more specific guidance, selecting/designing such a diagram seems likely to be opinion-based, in terms of what concepts are included/emphasized and which ones are de-emphasized, what relationships are emphasized, etc.  Imagine if we had 3 candidate diagrams -- I'm not seeing clear criteria articulated in the question that could be used to select between those candidates.